# How many min, max and saddle points does $f(x,y) = (x+y)\sin(x-y)$ have?

Tags: calculus

**Question:** Plot the surface to the function $f(x,y) = (x+y)\sin(x-y)$ and answer how many $min$, $max$ and $saddle$ points there are in $R^2$.

[image]

So this is a plot of the function. How on earth can I see how many min, max and saddle points there are here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f_{xx}f_{yy} − f^2_{xy} < 0$ at $(a, b)$ then $(a, b)$ is a saddle point.

If $f_{xx}f_{yy} − f^2_{xy} > 0$ at $(a, b)$ then $(a, b)$ is either a maximum or a minimum.

Distinguish between these as follows:

– if $f_{xx} < 0$ and $f_{yy} < 0$ at $(a, b)$ then $(a, b)$ is a maximum point.

– if $f_{xx} > 0$ and $f_{yy} > 0$ at $(a, b)$ then $(a, b)$ is a minimum point.

Now $f(x,y) = (x+y) \sin(x-y)$ then
$$f_x = \sin(x-y) + (x+y)\cos(x-y)$$
$$f_{xx} = 2\cos(x-y) - (x+y)\sin(x-y)$$
$$f_{xy} = (x+y)\sin(x-y)$$
$$f_y = -\sin(x-y) - (x+y)\cos(x-y)$$
$$f_{yy} = 2\cos(x-y) - (x+y)\sin(x-y)$$
Note that $f_{xx}=f_{yy}$.

$$f_{xx}f_{yy} − f^2_{xy} = 4\cos^2(x-y) - 4(x+y)\sin(x-y)\cos(x-y)$$

**Saddle points:**
The point $(a,b)$ is a saddle point if $$\cos^2(a-b) > \frac{1}{2}(a+b)\sin(2a-2b)$$
**Max point:**
The point $(a,b)$ is a Max point if $$\left(\cos^2(a-b) < \frac{1}{2}(a+b)\sin(2a-2b)\right) ~\mbox{and}~ \left(\cos(a-b) < \frac{1}{2}(a+b)\sin(a-b)\right)$$

**Min point:**
The point $(a,b)$ is a Min point if $$\left(\cos^2(a-b) < \frac{1}{2}(a+b)\sin(2a-2b)\right) ~\mbox{and}~ \left(\cos(a-b) > \frac{1}{2}(a+b)\sin(a-b)\right)$$